# PySide\PyQt - Menu Add Action at index (before or between)

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyside, qmenu

I'm creating a custom context menu for a widget in PySide, and I want to preserve Standard menu options, but I want to put them after custom actions.

Is there a way to add actions to `QMenu` and set specific order for them?

Here's my current code:

```
def buildRightClickMenu(self):

    self.textBox.setContextMenuPolicy(Qt.CustomContextMenu)
    self.textBox.customContextMenuRequested.connect(self.contextMenuRequested)

    self.actionSave = QAction(self)
    self.actionSave.setText("Save File")
    self.actionSave.triggered.connect(self.saveFile)

    self.actionOpen = QAction(self)
    self.actionOpen.setText("Open File")
    self.actionOpen.triggered.connect(self.openFile)


    self.menu = self.textBox.createStandardContextMenu()

    self.menu.addSeparator()
    self.menu.addAction(self.actionOpen)
```

As expected, this first creates default menu options, and adds a separator and `actionOpen` afterwards. I want to put `actionOpen` at the start of the context menu, followed by default actions for the widget.

Comment: TFM says: [insertAction](https://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qwidget.html#insertAction).

Comment: Oh, right. It's in QWidget. Can I say "Thanks" here? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is `PySide.QtGui.QWidget.insertAction(before, action)`, in QWidget class.

[PySide - Insert action](https://srinikom.github.io/pyside-docs/PySide/QtGui/QWidget.html#PySide.QtGui.PySide.QtGui.QWidget.insertAction)